# only last entry is shown in csv file during reading?

Tags: android, csv, opencsv

i am reading a file using the following code

`FileReader fr=new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/content.csv");

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String reader = "";
        while ((reader = in.readLine()) != null){
            String[] RowData = reader.split(",");
            id = RowData[0];
            path = RowData[1];`
```

and i have also tried using the opencsv class but with both the method i am only able to read the last entry in the file..
what am i missing?can someone explain to me?

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/playlist_record.csv");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String reader = "";
        while ((reader = in.readLine()) != null){
            String[] RowData = reader.split(",");
            id = RowData[0];
            path = RowData[1];
            type= RowData[2];
            update= RowData[3];
            server= RowData[4];
         t1.setText(id);
           // t1.append(path);
          //  t1.append(type);
           // t1.append(server);
        }
        in.close();
```

this is my code i am using to read the file

Comment: think you should show us a few more lines of code here - your basic idea seems right

Comment: The line t1.setText(id) overwrites your textfield value every time you read a new line. In this case the last line wins and is shown. Try to use append every time.